# Stock Control Determinant

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a table that has a Stock In, Stock Out, and (Stock In - Stock Out). I want the difference between the in and out stocks to be calculated based on the proceeding resulting from (Stock In - Stock Out). I.e

```
Stock In |Stock Out|(Stock In - Stock Out)|

500      |    50   |    450               |

450      |    100  |    350               |
```

The problem I'm having is that Stock Out is deducting from original Stock In of 500.

The result, I'm having is this:

```
Stock In |Stock Out|(Stock In - Stock Out)|

500      |    50   |    450               |

0        |    100  |    400               |

0        |    150  |    350               |
```

I want it to be deducted from the result of their differences.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  Product_Code,  SUM(Stock In - Stock Out) AS Stock_Balance
FROM Daily_Stock_Balance
GROUP BY  Product_Code;
```

This is the result I'm getting from the above query:

```
     Stock In |Stock Out|Stock Balance|

     500      |    50   |    450      |

              |    100  |    100      |

              |    150  |   100       |
```

Below is my real database table
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your query???

Comment: Hi Vignesh, I just edit my post to have the query. You can have a look again. Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you want.

Comment: I want stock_balance' result i.e. (-168163) to be added to quantity received in the next row i.e. where I have quantity loaded as (727000)and subsequently deducted by quantity_loaded i.e. (727000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about summing the relevant columns:

```
SELECT Testx.dispatchdate,
       Testx.stockin,
       Testx.stockout,
       (SELECT SUM(stockin)
        FROM   Testx a
        WHERE  a.dispatchdate <= Testx.dispatchdate) AS SumIn,
       (SELECT SUM(stockout)
        FROM   Testx a
        WHERE  a.dispatchdate <= Testx.dispatchdate) AS SumOut,
       [sumin] - [sumout]                            AS Balance
FROM   Testx
ORDER  BY Testx.dispatchdate;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been away for a while that's why I was unable to test and feed you back if the code actually worked. I must confess it does works as expected. Thanks a bunch!