# MS Access Query that retains previous balance

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a running balance similar to a bank statement such that a beginning balance is calculated then
as records are read, either the debit amount or the credit amount is added initially to the beginning balance
then from that resulting calculation the next record's debit or credit is added to show the next value.
There are separate 'Where' conditions for gathering the beginng balance, the credits and the debits

The difficulty I am having is retaining the calculated balance from one record to the next.

The output should look like this:

```
EmpCode  Credit    Debit    Balance
EC100    null      null     $1000.00
null     null      $500.00  $1500.00
null     null      $100.00  $1600.00
null     $50.00    null     $1550.00
null     $100.00   null     $1450.00

Emp. Totals                    $1450.00
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112242/stock-control-determinant/22113468#22113468 ? I do not see how you are to reproduce exactly what you want outside of a report. A report will allow a running sum.

Comment: @user3278957, on what field is your query sorted?

Comment: Query field is 'EntryDate'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a date column or really any column by which you can establish order then you can do a query like this. In this example the transactions are in one column with positive values

```
SELECT Outside.DateField
, Outside.AmountDollars
, (select sum(Inside.AmountDollars)  
          from Table2 Inside  
          where Inside.DateField <=Outside.DateField) as Balance
FROM Table2 Outside
```

Comment: Thank you so much I got solution.